# Condition for finite $\infty$-norm of a transfer function

Tags: normed-spaces, control-theory

I am reading "Feedback control theory" by Doyle, Francis and Tannenbaum [DFT](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229091401_Feedback_Control_Theory).

Lemma 1 on page 16 states: the $\infty$-norm of a transfer function $G$ is finite iff $G$ is proper and has no poles on the imaginary axis.

I am wondering why stability of $G$ doesn't come into the picture here.

Comment: Because they define it to be the supremum on the imaginary axis and not on the closed right half plane.

Comment: Does that mean the definition applies to unstable transfer functions?

Comment: As long as the transfer function does not have poles on the imaginary axis.